# Observable.FromEventHandler Subscribe to Action

Tags: c#, observable

Subscribing to Control events using Observable.FromEventHandler is very easy using Reactive Extensions; However, when it comes to a custom control's Actions i cant subscribe to their invocation using the same method as it results in an error saying

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Reactive.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code`

My custom control code

```
public partial class Hub : UserControl
{
    public Action<bool> OnButtonStartClick { get; set; }

    public Hub()
    {
        Observable.FromEventPattern(buttonHide, "Click", new ControlScheduler(this)).Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            if (null != OnButtonHideClick)
                OnButtonHideClick.Invoke(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Trying to subscribe as following

```
private void InitializeEventHandlers()
{
    Observable.FromEventPattern(MainHub, "OnButtonStartClick").Subscribe(_ =>
    {
          //DO SOMETHING AS USUAL!
    });
}
```